# Как открыть страницу вордпресса с помощью FTP

Tags: wordpress, ftp

Как открыть страницу  созданную на основе моего шаблона вордпресса с помощью FTP для редактирования?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Страница в WP - это некий контент в базе, плюс код, который из него создаёт html. По FTP вам открывать нечего. Нет нигде html для редактирования.

Используйте админку WP для внесения изменений на страницы.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.